# Oozie Invalid Transition

Tags: oozie

```
<workflow-app name="Oozie_app" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
        <start to="TransformWeatherData"/>
        <action name="TransformWeatherData">
                <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
                        <exec>/home/kingsly/working_directory/copyFromLocal.sh</exec>
                        <file>/home/kingsly/working_directory/copyFromLocal.sh</file>
                </shell>
                <ok to="Oozie_app"/>
                <error to="end"/>
        </action>
        <end name='end' />
```

I am new to Oozie and i have created a workflow and job.properties file 
This is how my workflow.xml looks
When i submit this workflow i am getting error as

```
Error: E0708 : E0708: Invalid transition, node [TransformWeatherData] transition [Oozie_app]
```

please help me resolve this .
My main objective is to move a file from local machine to HDfs and i have included the Hadoop command in the shell script

Answer (score 2):

You were referring to a missing node. I fixed this:

```
<workflow-app name="Oozie_app" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
        <start to="TransformWeatherData"/>
        <action name="TransformWeatherData">
                <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <configuration>
                <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>default</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
                        <exec>/home/kingsly/working_directory/copyFromLocal.sh</exec>
                        <file>/home/kingsly/working_directory/copyFromLocal.sh</file>
                </shell>
                <ok to="end"/>
                <error to="kill" />
        </action>
       <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name='end' />
```